# Cordova/Chromecast: "For some reason, not attempting to join route"

Tags: html, cordova, chromecast

I have a simple Cordova app with a video HTML5 element. I try to cast this video to a Chromecast. It won't display the Chromecast icon as default (if Chromecast is available) so I using a plugin.

I'm using the "cordova-plugin-chromecast". By calling `chrome.cast.initialize`, the next error will be logged:

```
"For some reason, not attempting to join route Chromecast, null, false".
```

And I cannot call a session.

Chromecast is connected, confirmed by the Google Home app on the device.

Why this log error?

Answer (score 0):

If you're integrating Chromecast/Google Cast into Cordova, this plugin is the most suggested one - [cordova-plugin-connectsdk](http://connectsdk.com/docs/1-6-0/cordova/setup-instructions/). Check this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45058938/integrate-chromecast-google-cast-into-ionic-or-cordova) for more details.